# How to move yield statement into separate method in tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
async def service(checker_config):
    alert_model_path = 'components.checker.service.AlertModel'
    ...
    with mock.patch(alert_model_path, AlertModelDev):
          yield CheckerService(checker_config)
```

How to move the body of the method `service` into a separate method?

I tried this:

```
@contextmanager
def mock_models(checker_config):
    alert_model_path = 'components.checker.service.AlertModel'
    ...
    with mock.patch(alert_model_path, AlertModelDev):
            yield CheckerService(checker_config)

@pytest.fixture
async def service(checker_config):
    with mock_models(checker_config):
         yeild
```

but it doesn't work. what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'. Does it throw an error? Does it not do what you want?

Comment: You probably want the `yield from` statement.

Comment: @MegaIng thanks, it doesn't return `CheckerService`, it return `None` instead. Where do I need to use `yield from`? inside `async` method?